# Is google play services app required for GCM to work?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-logcat, google-cloud-messaging

I was trying to run the Google Cloud Messaging code on Eclipse. The Error SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE was coming on emulator and a tablet running 2.2.

So after looking on the internet for some time i included isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() check in my code which returned status code 1 meaning SERVICE_MISSING.

from developer.android.com docs i came to know this

To test your app when using the Google Play services SDK, you must use either:

- A compatible Android device that runs Android 2.2 or higher and includes Google Play Store.
- The Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.

So my question is that for registering an android 2.2 device which has a Google Play app, is Google play services required as well? 
Since my tablet is running on android 2.2 with a google play app but no google play services and the emulator i was running was less than 4.2.2, is this the reason that GCM was giving an error of SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE.
I didn't see any other error in Logcat as well.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: did you synchronize your gmail account with the tablet?

Comment: yes i added a gmail account in the tablet...

Answer (score 2):

> So my question is that for registering an android 2.2 device which has a Google Play app, is Google play services required as well?

If you are going to use `GoogleCloudMessaging`, my understanding is yes, you need Play Services. The older GCM API that does not use the `GoogleCloudMessaging` class should work on devices without Play Services, as it worked on such devices before Google I|O 2013, when there was no `GoogleCloudMessaging` class.

Comment: Does the app have to be distributed with the Play store to user GCM?

Comment: @DalvikVM: Presumably not, otherwise we couldn't test our apps as developers from IDEs and such. The device needs to have the Play Services framework installed, though.